# How do I troubleshoot a breaker tripping when I plug in a gas dryer?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, dryer

I recently moved into a house and purchased a new washer and gas dryer. In the laundry room, there are two GFCI outlets, one on the side wall near the light switch, and one behind the washer and dryer. These two are on different circuits, both 15amp. The installer hooked up the washer first and plugged it into the back wall and turned it on and it seemed to work. Then they hooked up the gas dryer and tested it, but the drum wouldn't turn and was making a grinding noise. The installer immediately said it was defective and took it back. Later, I noticed the washer wasn't actually working - the drum was barely turning. I thought it unlikely both would be bad, and I was able to reach the cord to the side outlet. The washer worked correctly in that outlet. I hired an electrician who looked at the outlet behind the appliances and thought it could be any of several different problems with the circuit. The easiest fix seemed to be extending the outlet that was working to be behind the washer and dryer.

This new outlet worked fine for the washer. The replacement dryer was delivered today, and as soon as the dryer was plugged in, the breaker tripped - basically instantly before the plug is even fully inserted. This happens even if it is the only thing plugged in. The installer suggested running an extension cord to another outlet to test the dryer. When plugged into an extension cord and connected to an outlet in the garage, it does not trip and the dryer seems to work. The installer tells me the dryer is fine, and I have a problem with my circuit. The circuit is 15amps which I'm guessing might not be enough for both washer and dryer at the same time, but I don't understand why it trips when only the dryer is plugged in (and not even under load). None of the breakers are labeled so I'm not sure which breaker the garage circuit uses.

Here's a picture of the panel. The new outlet is on the lower half of slot 11, indicated with the arrow.
[image: panel]

I have a lot of questions, but essentially, how do I troubleshoot this and ensure that it gets fixed correctly? I want to at least determine if there's a problem with the dryer before I call an electrician.

If there's enough info to determine the problem, what are my options? We are planning to upgrade the panel in the future to add circuits for a kiln and probably an electric dryer, so I kind of prefer to just get it working now, but if big changes are needed, it might be worth tackling that now instead of spending a lot to get a gas dryer working.

Edit: Checked continuity on dryer with a multimeter and it appears correct - continuity between ground and case, no continuity between hot, neutral, ground. The outlet was tested with a 3-light tester at inspection (prior to being extended) and it indicated it was wired correctly. I will check it again as soon as I can find where I put the tester.

Comment: Not sure exact scenario, but I suspect some variant of a ground fault or neutral-ground bond problem. Do you have a [three light tester](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Receptacle-Tester-RT110/206517828)? Make sure it is a simple one - three lights, no numeric/LCD/LED/etc. display. Check the receptacles in the laundry room and the garage. Anything showing reverse hot/neutral or missing ground etc. get it resolved first. If that all checks out OK (bad in laundry or in garage could make the dryer work in one and not the other). Once that's checked out,

Comment: use a [multimeter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-600-Volt-Digital-Multi-Meter-Manual-Ranging-MM325/320822947) to check continuity on the dryer. You should have continuity between the ground pin and the case, no continuity between hot and neutral, between hot and ground, between hot and case, between neutral and ground or between neutral and case. Anything not proper, report it and we can come up with a diagnosis.

Comment: Correct, 15 Amp is not enough for both. The suspicion is you have faulty GFCI since it works on the NON-GFCI circuit. In any case you need to inspect that wiring

Comment: An overload won't pop the breaker the moment you plug it in. This has to be a ground fault or bonding problem in the dryer.

Comment: @KMJ `Then they hooked up the gas dryer and tested it, but the drum wouldn't turn and was making a grinding noise. The installer immediately said it was defective and took it back` It is hard to belive that the seond dryer had same problem

Comment: I think the first dryer might have been OK, but was used on a bad circuit. It doesn't sound like it was ever tested on the GFCI.

Comment: @KMJ I also suspect there was not a problem with the first dryer, but I did not have the opportunity to troubleshoot it. It was never hooked up to the side wall circuit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact Updated the question with that info - continuity test checks out, currently looking for my 3-light tester that I misplaced in the chaos of moving :S but it did test correctly prior to being extended.

Comment: Simple triage and problem solving.  You have three outlets ... behind, beside, and in the garage.  You have two appliances, get a third one that is very simple and you know works, like a hair dryer.  Plug each of the three appliances into each of the three outlets.  That's 9 data points.  CLEARLY document what works and what doesn't.  That's not clear from your question.  You will probably know where the problem is before you do all nine tests and you probably won't have to ask questions here... just be methodical and logical about it.